# Assign variable to graph column in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I want change the columns AN, Z, AD from text to the column number which I will store as a integer variable.

```
            AChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            AChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Name = "=" & "'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!$AN$" & iStart
            AChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).XValues = "=" & "'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!$Z$" & iStart & ":$Z$" & iEnd
            AChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Values = "=" & "'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!$AD$" & iStart & ":$AD$" & iEnd
```

I tried "!C" & variable name but that didn't work.

Please help

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Not sure of the problem and can't test right now but I'd query `AChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Values` in the immediate window and use the returned string as a basis. In case you're not familiar with breakpoints & the immediate window search for "debugging VBA" e.g. https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code